# No such module 'XLPagerTabStrip'

Tags: swift4, xcode9.2, xlpagertabstrip

i use tutorial https://medium.com/michaeladeyeri/how-to-implement-android-like-tab-layouts-in-ios-using-swift-3-578516c3aa9 and get error `No such module 'XLPagerTabStrip'`

My Podfile

`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NewsTabs' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.0'

end
`

Comment: Did you run 'pod install' ?

Comment: @T. Pasichnyk, yes

Comment: I have fixed this issue by updating Pods.

Comment: Is this error when using the XLPagerTabStrip in your code or while you do pod install? @Jussia

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I set my App's Deployment Target set 10.0.
I have fixed this issue by updating Pods.

Step 1: Navigate to your project.
        cd /Users/Prakasha/Desktop/Workspace/Projects/YourApp

Step 2: pod update.
        this will update your system's all pod files.

thats it once updating completes, quit Xcode and reopened, bugs go away.